# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Scaling Trigger CPUUnitilization

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to change the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Scaling Trigger. I did the following:

1. Go to "AWS Management Console"
2. Click "Actions" -> "Edit Configuration"
3. Click "Auto Scaling" tab
4. I change the "Trigger Measurement" to "CPUUtulization."

I'd like to set "CPUUtilization > 60%"

But I couldn't find any text field to fill the 60%.

I'm developing the Beanstalk using Eclipse.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just need to scroll down.

http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/ documents the parameters.

Comment: providing documentation reference doesn't answer your original question. can you share what you came up with